# Pandas multiple dataframes into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looping through list with multiple dicionaries and want them to be appended into single data frame.

```
#getting values of specific key from AWS' boto3 response
events_list = response_event.get('Events')

for e in events_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e)
    print(df)
```

Current and expected result below:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
   col1  col2
0     2     4
   col1  col2
0     3     5


   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
```

Comment: try printing `df` outside the `for loop`

Comment: Well `append` is a thing we do to lists (with the `append` method). The closest equivalent to dicts is maybe the `update` method which updates one dict with the contents of another.

Comment: @AnuragDabas I don't think that's going to help: he's overwriting df every loop. You could  concat the dataframes: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e) for e in event_list])`

Comment: @dm2 I know that for this `concat()` or `append()` method is used...That's why I am saying `try` because OP is printing df inside the `for loop` maybe he doesn't need furthur method as his dataframe was created and due to prining inside the for loop it is displaying like that...but seems like I was wrong...Btw Thnx for telling **:)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `concat`

```
out = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e) for e in events_list)
```

Comment: Great thanks! I noticed every row has `0` index though.

Comment: @marcin2x4 adding out = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e) for e in events_list).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Please note that this answers is not efficient for huge dataframes as it create a new dataframe for each line.